# how to delete(actually edit) images from edit page in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter, so I have very less knowledge about it. I need to edit the post from edit page. I am being able to edit everything except the pictures i uploaded. For pictures i either have to re-upload all the pictures i want or the images field will go empty. Here is my current code for edit:

```
    <body>

        <div class="container">
                                <strong>Edit Product</strong>
                      <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                                <?php echo form_open_multipart('/products/edit/'.$products['product_id']); ?>

                        <?php $error = form_error("product_name", "<p class='text-danger'>", '</p>'); ?>

                                    <div class="form-group <?php echo $error ? 'has-error' : '' ?>">
                                        <label for="product_name">Product_Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="product_name" value="<?php echo $products['product_name'] ?>" id="product_name" class="form-control">
                                        </div>



                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label>Picture</label>
                                  <input class="form-control" type="file" name="picture[]" multiple />
                              </div>

                              <div class="container">
                            <?php

                                // explode images into a variable
                                $images=explode(',',$show['images']);
                             ?>
                             <?php foreach($images as $key=>$val){ ?>
                              <?php //echo ($val);?>
                               <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/images/').$val;?>" />
                              <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Remove" />
                                </div>
                               </div>
                               <?php } ?>
                            </div>



                                    <input type="submit" value="Create Product" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <?php echo form_close(); ?>

            </div>

      </body>
```

This is my edit function on controller:

```
                  public function edit($id)
          {
              #code
              $data['show']=$this->product_model->get_product_by_id($id);
              if(empty($data['show']))
              {
                show_404();
              }
              $this->load->helper('form');
              $this->load->library('form_validation');
              $data['products']=$this->product_model->get_product_by_id($id);
              $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_name','Product_Name','required');
              $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_price','Product_Price','required');
              $this->form_validation->set_rules('produce_description','Produce_Description','required');

              if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
              {
                $this->load->view('products/edit',$data);
              }

              else {
                $this->product_model->set_product($id);
                redirect('/');
              }
          }
```

And this is my set_product function to save everything in databse:

```
    public function set_product($id=0){
                 $picture=array();
                 $count=count($_FILES['picture']['name']);
                 //Check whether user upload picture
                 if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])){
                     foreach($_FILES as $value){
                         for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++){
                             $_FILES['picture']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
                             $_FILES['picture']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
                             $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
                             $_FILES['picture']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
                             $_FILES['picture']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];
                             $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/images/';
                             $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
                             $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['picture']['name'];

                             //Load upload library and initialize configuration
                             $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                             $this->upload->initialize($config);
                             // print_r($value['name'][$s]);exit;
                             if($this->upload->do_upload('picture')){
                                 $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                                 $picture[] = $uploadData['file_name'];
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }//end of first if
                 $data=array('product_name'=>$this->input->post('product_name'));

                 if ($id==0){
                      $this->db->insert('products',$data);
                      $last_id = $this->db->insert_id();
                      if(!empty($picture)){
                          foreach($picture as $p_index=>$p_value) {
                             $this->db->insert('images', array('product_id'=>$last_id,'images'=>$p_value));
                          }
                      }
                 }
                 else {
                     $this->db->where('id',$id);
                     $this->db->update('products',$data);
                     if(!empty($picture)){
                         foreach($picture as $p_index=>$p_value) {
                            $this->db->update('images', array('product_id'=>$last_id,'images'=>$p_value) ); // --> this one?
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
```

This is how my edit page seems right now.[image: Editpage]
Now what i want to happen here is, when i click remove button then that particular picture only should be deleted and i should be able to upload additional picture with the remaining one, i,e which are not removed.
Can anyone help me please. Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are really destined to learn everything from SOF. My i suggest a tutorial for CI like http://codesamplez.com/codeigniter-tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LOGIC**

First, Understand the Logic/Concept what actually should happen in this case.

1. Click on the remove link

Now you have two options.
 i) send to URL and come back to this page 
 ii)Use Ajax

2. Delete the image from images table

Either through direct link or through Ajax you will send ID of the image, which you can easily delete by creating a function in the model.

3. Delete the image from uploads folder

There is a builtin PHP function unlink(path) which is used to delete files. You can do that in the same function which you will write to delete image from images table.

**How to Code**

In your view where the image is displayed you can link to a URL like

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'products/delImage/'.$images['id']?>" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</a>
```

But it only implies if you have images in product_images table. If you have images name in csv format in images column in your products table. You need to send product_id and image name to the model function and then use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function to remove the image name from the column.

Once you have done removing image you can redirect back to this page by using

```
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

**Edit**

If you have images table. You can divide your getProducts query like
(My table is properties)

```
$data=$this->db->query('SELECT property.*, users.name as posted_by, property_types.name as property_type
     from property
     inner join users on users.id=property.posted_by
     inner join property_types on property_types.id=property.type
     order by property.posted_date desc
     ')->result_array();

 for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
 {
      $data[$i]['images']=$this->db->query('SELECT * from property_images WHERE property_images.property_id='.$data[$i]['id'])->result_array();
 }

 return $data;
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, I will try this. And your link didn't open. Yeah i need to learn a lot. I am just starting. :)

Comment: $this->db->select("products.*, GROUP_CONCAT(images.images) as images", false);
      $this->db->from('products');
      $this->db->join('images', 'images.product_id=products.product_id', 'left');
      if($id)
      {
      $this->db->where('products.product_id', $id);
      }
      $this->db->group_by('products.product_id');
      $query=$this->db->get();
      return $query->row_array(); 
This is the query i used for selecting, I know it doesn't returns image_id. What SQL function should i use for selecting multiple columns with join.

Comment: the best way to do it is is to break your query in two parts. get the products first , loop through it and get images by product id and store it in an index

Comment: Can you please hit me with its SQL Query? I got what you told but couldn't make the query for it.

Comment: Thank you Sir. :) You took me out of a huge problem.

Comment: With the query i mentioned above this result used to come:  Array ( [product_id] => 1 [product_name] => Test [images] => ) Array ( [product_id] => 2 [product_name] => Test2 [images] => ) Array ( [product_id] => 3 [product_name] => jhgfdfghjk [images] => ) Array ( [product_id] => 4 [product_name] => hgfdf [images] => ) Array ( [product_id] => 8 [product_name] => gfdsdfgh [images] => 15400425_384280551914877_3607106669179553345_n.jpg,15400342_258695011214810_1240948716449811711_n.jpg ) . Now with your qurey this result came :

Comment: Array ( [product_id] => 8 [product_name] => gfdsdfgh [image_id] => 2 [images] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [image_id] => 1 [product_id] => 8 [images] => 15400342_258695011214810_1240948716449811711_n.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [image_id] => 2 [product_id] => 8 [images] => 15400425_384280551914877_3607106669179553345_n.jpg ) ) ) Array ( [product_id] => 8 [product_name] => gfdsdfgh [image_id] => 1 [images] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [image_id] => 1 [product_id] => 8 [images] => 15400342_258695011214810_1240948716449811711_n.jpg ) [1] =>

Comment: Array ( [image_id] => 2 [product_id] => 8 [images] => 15400425_384280551914877_3607106669179553345_n.jpg ) ) )

Comment: I customized the query like this:$data=$this->db->query('SELECT products.*, images.image_id as image_id, images.images as images
     from products
     inner join images on images.product_id=products.product_id
     order by products.product_id desc
     ')->result_array();

 for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
 {
      $data[$i]['images']=$this->db->query('SELECT * from images WHERE images.product_id='.$data[$i]['product_id'])->result_array();
 }

 return $data;

Comment: I am getting this result with this code in my view called landing_page:         <?php foreach ($products as $p): ?>

<?php
      print_r($p);
       endforeach;
      exit();
?>

Answer (score 1):

```
This is the controller function to delete image and its entry from the database:
<?php
public function delete()
{
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $imageName = $_GET['img_name'];
   $imgDir = "uploads/";
   $delImage = $imgDir.$imageName;
   unlink($delImage);
   $result = $this->admin_model->deleteImage($id);
   if($result)
   {
     $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg','<strong>This Image is deleted successfully.</strong>');
   }   
}
?>

This is the model function to delete image and called in the controller:
<?php
   public function deleteImage($id)
   {
        if($id!='') 
        {
          $data = array('id' => $id );
          $suc  = $this->db->delete('theme_master', $data);
        }

        if($suc){               
           return true;
        }else{
           return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: $id = $_GET['id'];
   $imageName = $_GET['img_name']; these two lines of code isn't working. how this code is supposed to get id and image name? I mean from where?

Comment: the browser threw this error:  Undefined index: img_name

Comment: You need to pass value through query string some thing like that: <a href="<?php echo base_url().'theme/delete/?id='.$images['id'].'&img_name='.$images['img_name']?>">Remove</a>

Comment: <a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo site_url('products/delete_image/'.$image_id[$i]); ?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this picture?')">Remove</a>

Comment: how to get the image name? $_GET['image_name']; What is image_name here?

Comment: You need to pass the image_name variable as a query string and you will get the value. just like $image_id['image_name']. in CodeIgniter use this to fetch the data $this->uri->segment(4);

Comment: if you have any issue please share your code and I will provide you the solution.